# json with gson value called "protected"

Tags: java, json, twitter, gson

Parsing twitter's json with gson,

Their schema includes a variable called 'protected'. I am unable to create a variable called protected for obvious reasons...

my resolution is to preform a replace on "protected": with something like "bProtected":

Can anyone think of a better solution?

Comment: Doesn't gson have a member name renaming annotation like Jackson has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GSON you can use `@SerializedName` trick:

```
   class SomeYourDeserializationClass {
      ...
        @SerializedName("protected")
        public String myProtected;
      ...
   }
```